# Existing dictionaries in list all being updated to new dictionary entry?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a simple program that contains a list of dictionaries. The grocery_history is the list of dictionaries, and the dictionary is grocery_item. Here is the code:

```
'''
The task is broken down into three sections.
Section 1 - User Input
Section 2 - loop through the grocery list
Section 3 - provide output to the console
'''


grocery_item = {}
grocery_history = []
stop = 'go'

while stop != 'q':
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = int(input("Quantity purchased:\n"))
    cost = float(input("Price per item:\n"))

    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item['number'] = quantity
    grocery_item['price'] = cost

    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

    stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
    print(grocery_history)

grand_total = 0 

for grocery_item in range(0, len(grocery_history)):

  item_total = grocery_history[grocery_item]['number'] * grocery_history[grocery_item]['price']
  grand_total += item_total

  print(str(grocery_history[grocery_item]['number']) + " " + grocery_history[grocery_item]['name'] + " @ $%.2f" % grocery_history[grocery_item]['price'] + " ea \t$%.2f" % item_total)

  item_total = 0.0

print("Grand total: $%.2f" % grand_total)
print(grocery_history)
```

In case you're wondering, the prompt for this assignment told me to use the variable grocery_item in my for loop. I normally would have chosen a different name since it becomes confusing. I also added a couple of print statements to print out the contents of grocery_history to see what's going wrong, and I confirmed it's when the dictionary is being added to the grocery_history list, that's when it for some reason updates existing dictionary items to match the new one being added. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, those comments were already there from the assignment prompt, I'll remove them from this post.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a new dictionary object each time in loop or else you end up using the same dictionary object so in effect replaces the already added one.

```
while stop != 'q':
    grocery_item = {}
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

sample code should work

```
grocery_history = []
stop = 'go'

while stop != 'q':
    item_name = input("Item name:\n")
    quantity = int(input("Quantity purchased:\n"))
    cost = float(input("Price per item:\n"))

    grocery_item = {}
    grocery_item['name'] = item_name
    grocery_item['number'] = quantity
    grocery_item['price'] = cost

    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

    stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")
    print(grocery_history)

grand_total = 0

for grocery_item in range(0, len(grocery_history)):

  item_total = grocery_history[grocery_item]['number'] * grocery_history[grocery_item]['price']
  grand_total += item_total

  print(str(grocery_history[grocery_item]['number']) + " " + grocery_history[grocery_item]['name'] + " @ $%.2f" % grocery_history[grocery_item]['price'] + " ea \t$%.2f" % item_total)

  item_total = 0.0

print("Grand total: $%.2f" % grand_total)
print(grocery_history)
```

the problem happened because you are repeating using same dict, although it adds to list each time, what you actually doing is keep updating the same reference so all content in the list becomes the same value
move dict inside solve the problem

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. For some odd reason, the assignment prompt told me to create the empty dictionary at the top with the empty list instead of in the loop... I tried what you said and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your loop does not create a new `grocery_item` object each time; it just updates the *same* `grocery_item` object over and over.

`grocery_history` ends up containing multiple *references* to this single object, in its latest state.

To fix this issue, move the line `grocery_item = {}` to be the first item underneath the  `while stop != 'q':` loop.  This will create a *new* object each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `sum` to get grand_total

```py
grocery_history = []
stop = 'go'

while stop != 'q':
    grocery_item = {}

    grocery_item['name'] = input("Item name:\n")
    grocery_item['number'] = int(input("Quantity purchased:\n"))
    grocery_item['price'] = float(input("Price per item:\n"))

    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

    stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\nType 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")

grand_total = sum(map(lambda item: item['number'] * item['price'], grocery_history))

print("Grand total: $%.2f" % grand_total)
print(grocery_history)
```

**Input:**

```
Item name:
item
Quantity purchased:
2
Price per item:
1.2
Would you like to enter another item?
Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:
q
```

**Output:**

```
Grand total: $2.40
[{'name': 'item', 'number': 2, 'price': 1.2}]
```